# Create date format from concatenating date, hour and minute in string format

Tags: date, time, calendar, timestamp, google-bigquery

I want to calculate number of hours between "first login" to event "Sign in" in Bigquery.

I have date, hour and minute in string format.

I have number of lines with eventAction = 'Sign Up Completion'  or visitNumber = 1, and use min() function to find the earliest time.

After all I want to calculate the difference between two times in hours.

My question is - what is the right concatenation between date, hits.hour and hits.minute - TIMESTAMP(date) + TIMESTAMP(hits.hour) + TIMESTAMP(hits.minute) - is not working good.

I use this query:

```
SELECT
  aaa.fullVisitorId,
  Signup_time - Reg_time  
FROM (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    MIN(TIMESTAMP(date) + TIMESTAMP(hits.hour) +
        TIMESTAMP(hits.minute)) AS Signup_time
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([gapXXX],
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-36,'DAY'),
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-9,'DAY'))
  WHERE eventAction = 'Sign Up Completion'
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId ) AS aaa
JOIN (
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    MIN(TIMESTAMP(date) + TIMESTAMP(hits.hour) +
        TIMESTAMP(hits.minute)) AS Reg_time
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([gapXXX],
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-36,'DAY'),
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-9,'DAY'))
  WHERE visitNumber = 1
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId) AS bbb
ON aaa.fullVisitorId = bbb.fullVisitorId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the right concatenation between date, hour and minute - TIMESTAMP(date) + TIMESTAMP(hits.hour) + TIMESTAMP(hits.minute) - is not working good?

Instead of using `hits.hour` and `hits.minute` I would recommend using `hits.time`

From [BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719):

```sql
hits.time   INTEGER The number of milliseconds after the visitStartTime when this  
                    hit was registered. The first hit has a hits.time of 0
```

So (for BigQuery Standard SQL) you can calculate hit start time as

```sql
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1000 * visitStartTime + hit.time) AS hitStart
```

If you need to stay with BigQuery Legacy SQL – you can use [`MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#msec_to_timestamp) instead of [`TIMESTAMP_MILLIS()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_millis)

> After all I want to calculate the difference between two times in hours.

For Standard SQL – you can use [`TIMESTAMP_DIFF()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff) as

```sql
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Timestamp1, Timestamp2, HOUR)
```

Or for Legacy SQL – you can use

```sql
(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(Timestamp1) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(Timestamp2))/3600
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail,  But hits.hour and hits.minute are names of fields in my data. I don't have one field with date, hour, minutes and seconds combination, only 3 fields in string format...

Comment: @Raya - is your table - google analytics data? that was my assumption. If it is GA data  - please read my answer again!! if it is not  - just let us know - so there will be no confusion

Comment: we have GA360 and I work with BigQuery with all data that we save and show in Google Analytics. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Raya - so yo do not see hits.time field in your table schema? please confirm! that is what you would expect to have based on https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719

Comment: I have hits.time in my schema, but this number is reset(start to be zero) at the begging of each session. And I know that my users don't always 'Sign Up' in the same session as they did first login.

Comment: @Raya - as I pointed in my answer  - visitStartTime  and hits.time gives you the time you are looking for specific hit :o) just try to stay aside for a sec from your initial idea of using minute and hour - so you willhave chance to get into right direction :o)

Comment: THANK YOU! You are right!Thank  you for your patience!